# Add new input text and save data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to create a dynamic form.
The user can add new input box to the form and define if this is gonna be used for text, number or date, he can add N input box

How can I create dynamic forms and then save the data in a database
And what is the best way to save the data in a sql server table?

thanks

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: He want to save anything, color, weight, position, age, whatever

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is a Form Designer. It can be done as a simple student project, to some large framework supporting lots of features.

A lot of the convenience tools that Asp.Net MVC provides will not be very useful to you and you need to get lower-level to handle this.

Also, lots of architecture decisions will arise, and making the wrong decision in each step can lead to a useless product.
An Exmaple:
Are you going to store all user data in a single table, or you'll create database tables that will match user designs?

Are you going to allow inter-field relationships: Field B is invisible/disabled unless someone fill field B.

What I'm trying to say is that this is deeper than what can be covered in a SO answer.

Comment: you'r right. I think he no need more than 20 input boxes

Comment: I guess you have a main entity and you want the admin to define custom properties for this entity and then the user has to fill these additional fields as companion attributes of the main entity. is that correct?